# Custom Wordpress site load error

Tags: php, wordpress, function, wamp

My company had a custom wordpress site created and when we are trying to load it into a WAMP server, the pages are not loading. Instead we are getting the actual page code and errors which is leaving my boss scratching his head and I want to see if I can get someone to help us out and figure out why this is not loading properly. Can anyone shed some light as to why we are receiving the following issues.

We are getting the following error:

```
Query is not defined

jQuery(function(){
```

And also we are getting a bunch of code and jibberish like the following:

```
__( 'Header Menu' ), 'footer-menu' => __( 'Footer Menu' ) ) ); } add_action( 'init', 'register_my_menus' ); add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' ); add_image_size( 'home-header', 1920, 550 ); //home header image add_image_size( 'home-short-story', 303, 363 ); // home short story image add_image_size( 'news-article-sidebar-thumbnail', 90, 90, true ); //sidebar news add_image_size( 'sidebar-promo-box-image', 125, 100, true); // blue custom sidebar widget image add_image_size( 'program-image', 221, 197, true); //program listing add_image_size( 'program-type-image', 372, 221, true); // /programs view add_image_size( 'directors-headshot', 194, 230, true); //directors image of directors add_image_size( 'news-article-listing-image', 194, 230, true); add_image_size( 'staff-headshot', 104, 120, true); // images of staff add_image_size( 'footer-logos', 60, 60); // footer logos add_image_size( 'page-header', 1920, 199, true); // header for page add_image_size( 'google-maps', 302, 138); // contact us sidebar google maps image add_action( 'init', 'create_post_type' ); function formatDate($startingDate,$endingDate,$startingTime,$endingTime,$shorter=false){ $return=''; $month=($shorter) ? 'M' : 'F'; $start_d = mysql2date('j', $startingDate); $end_d = mysql2date('j', $endingDate); $start_m = mysql2date('m', $startingDate); $end_m = mysql2date('m', $endingDate); if($start_m == $end_m){ if($start_d == $end_d){ $return.=mysql2date($month.' j, Y', $startingDate); }else{ $return.=mysql2date($month.' j', $startingDate); $return.=mysql2date(' - j, Y', $endingDate); } } else{ $return.=mysql2date($month.' j', $startingDate); $return.=mysql2date(' - '.$month.' j, Y', $endingDate); } if($startingTime){ $return.=' ( '.$startingTime; if($endingTime){ $return.=' - '.$endingTime; } $return.=' )'; } return $return; } function create_post_type() { /*if ( !post_type_exists( 'news-and-research' ) ) { register_post_type( 'news-and-research', array( 'labels' => array( 'name' => __( 'News & Research' ), 'singular_name' => __( 'News & Research' ) ), 'public' => true, 'has_archive' => false, 'hierarchical' => true, 'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt', 'page-attributes', 'comments' ) ) ); }*/ if ( !post_type_exists( 'quotes' ) ) { register_post_type( 'quotes', array( 'labels' => array( 'name' => __( 'Quotes' ), 'singular_name' => __( 'Quotes' ) ), 'public' => true, 'has_archive' => false, 'hierarchical' => true, 'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'page-attributes' ) ) ); } if ( !post_type_exists( 'programs' ) ) { register_post_type( 'programs', array( 'labels' => array( 'name' => __( 'Programs' ), 'singular_name' => __( 'Programs' ) ), 'public' => true, 'has_archive' => false, 'hierarchical' => true, 'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt', 'page-attributes' ) ) ); } if ( !post_type_exists( 'lodging-template' ) ) { register_post_type( 'lodging-template', array( 'labels' => array( 'name' => __( 'Lodging Templates' ), 'singular_name' => __( 'Lodging Template' ) ), 'public' => true, 'has_archive' => false, 'hierarchical' => true, 'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt', 'page-attributes' ) ) ); } if ( !post_type_exists( 'activities-template' ) ) { register_post_type( 'activities-template', array( 'labels' => array( 'name' => __( 'Activities Templates' ), 'singular_name' => __( 'Activity Template' ) ), 'public' => true, 'has_archive' => false, 'hierarchical' => true, 'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt', 'page-attributes' ) ) ); } if ( !post_type_exists( 'application-template' ) ) { register_post_type( 'application-template', array( 'labels' => array( 'name' => __( 'Application Templates' ), 'singular_name' => __( 'Application Template' ) ), 'public' => true, 'has_archive' => false, 'hierarchical' => true, 'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt', 'page-attributes' ) ) ); } flush_rewrite_rules( false ); } //use parent template (Propose a program, People) function set_page_template_to_parent() { global $post; if (is_page()) { if ($post->post_parent == 0) return true; else if (($post->post_parent != $post->ID) && ($post->post_parent==64 || $post->post_parent==97)) { $parent_page_template = get_post_meta($post->post_parent,'_wp_page_template',true); $template = TEMPLATEPATH . "/{$parent_page_template}"; if (file_exists($template)) { load_template($template); exit; } } } } add_action('template_redirect','set_page_template_to_parent'); function build_menu($menu_name) { if( ! $menu_name ) return false; $menu_locations = get_nav_menu_locations(); if( ! isset( $menu_locations[$menu_name] ) ) return false; $menu_obj = get_term( $menu_locations[$menu_name], 'nav_menu' ); if( ! $menu_obj ) return false; $menu_id = $menu_obj->term_id; $url = get_permalink( $post->ID ); $homeurl = get_home_url().'/'; $args = array( 'order' => 'ASC', 'orderby' => 'menu_order', 'post_type' => 'nav_menu_item', 'post_status' => 'publish', 'output' => ARRAY_A, 'output_key' => 'menu_order', 'nopaging' => true, 'update_post_term_cache' => false ); $items = wp_get_nav_menu_items( $menu_id, $args ); if( !count($items) > 0 ) return false; $children = array(); $i = 0; foreach( $items as $parent ) { if( $parent->post_status == 'publish' && $parent->menu_item_parent != '0' ) // Is child { $page_id = $parent->menu_item_parent; $children[$page_id][$i]['url'] = $parent->url; $children[$page_id][$i]['title'] = $parent->title; $i++; } } $menu = ''; $menu .= '

    '; foreach( $items as $item ) // Loop through and get top level items { if( $item->post_status == 'publish' && $item->menu_item_parent == '0' ) // Is top level { if( array_key_exists($item->ID, $children) ) // If has children { $menu .= '
    '; $menu .= ''.$item->title.''; $menu .= '
        '; foreach( $children[$item->ID] as $child ) { if($url === $item->url) { $menu .= '
        '.$child['title'].'
        '; } else { $menu .= '
        '.$child['title'].'
        '; } } $menu .= ''; $menu .= '
    '; } else { if($url === $item->url || $homeurl === $item->url) { $menu .= '
    '.$item->title.'
    '; } else { $menu .= '
    '.$item->title.'
    '; } } } } $menu .= '

'; echo $menu; } function build_menu_footer($menu_name) { if( ! $menu_name ) return false; $menu_locations = get_nav_menu_locations(); if( ! isset( $menu_locations[$menu_name] ) ) return false; $menu_obj = get_term( $menu_locations[$menu_name], 'nav_menu' ); if( ! $menu_obj ) return false; $menu_id = $menu_obj->term_id; $url = get_permalink( $post->ID ); $homeurl = get_home_url().'/'; $args = array( 'order' => 'ASC', 'orderby' => 'menu_order', 'post_type' => 'nav_menu_item', 'post_status' => 'publish', 'output' => ARRAY_A, 'output_key' => 'menu_order', 'nopaging' => true, 'update_post_term_cache' => false ); $items = wp_get_nav_menu_items( $menu_id, $args ); if( !count($items) > 0 ) return false; $children = array(); $i = 0; foreach( $items as $parent ) { if( $parent->post_status == 'publish' && $parent->menu_item_parent != '0' ) // Is child { $page_id = $parent->menu_item_parent; $children[$page_id][$i]['url'] = $parent->url; $children[$page_id][$i]['title'] = $parent->title; $i++; } } $menu = ''; $width = array('wp39','wp22','wp24','wp15'); $i=0; $column1 = true; $st = 0; foreach( $items as $item ) // Loop through and get top level items { if( $item->post_status == 'publish' && $item->menu_item_parent == '0' ) // Is top level { if( array_key_exists($item->ID, $children) ) // If has children { $menu .= '
'; $menu .= '
'.$item->title.'
'; $menu .= '

    '; foreach( $children[$item->ID] as $child ) { if($column1){ $class = ($st%2!=0)?"wp44":"wp46"; if($url === $item->url) { $menu .= '
    '.$child['title'].'
    '; } else { $menu .= '
    '.$child['title'].'
    '; } } else { if($url === $item->url) { $menu .= '
    '.$child['title'].'
    '; } else { $menu .= '
    '.$child['title'].'
    '; } } $st++; } if($column1){ $menu .= '
    '; } $menu .= '

'; $column1 = false; $menu .= '
'; } else { if($url === $item->url || $homeurl === $item->url) { $menu .= '
'; $menu .= '
'.$item->title.'
'; $menu .= '
'; } else { $menu .= '
'; $menu .= '
'.$item->title.'
'; $menu .= '
'; } } $i++; if($i%4==0){ $menu .= '
'; $i=0; } } } echo $menu; } function year_format($year){ if($year<10){ return '0'.$year; } return $year; } function head_img($image){ if($image){ $image=$image['sizes']['page-header']; echo 'style="background-image: url('.$image.');"'; } else { $image=get_field('default_header_image','options'); echo 'style="background-image: url('.$image['sizes']['page-header'].');"'; } } function custom_excerpt_length( $length ) { return 45; } add_filter( 'excerpt_length', 'custom_excerpt_length', 999 ); /*function add_jquery_data() { global $post_type; if ( isset( $_GET['action'] ) && $_GET['action'] == 'edit' && $post_type='programs') { ?> 'http://www.ipam.ucla.edu/elements/choose.aspx?pc='.strtolower(get_field('program_code')) ), $atts)); return ''.$title.''; } return false; } function programEmailShortcode() { if(get_field('program_code')){ return ''.strtolower(get_field('program_code')).'@ipam.ucla.edu'; } return false; } function programCategory($post,$parentCode){ // show to which long program is set $workshopOrLecture=array(48,52); $partOfProgram=array(); if(trim($parentCode)!='' && in_array($post->post_parent,$workshopOrLecture)){ $args = array( 'post_parent' => 41, 'post_type' => 'programs', 'posts_per_page' => 1, 'post_status' => array('publish'), 'meta_query' => array( 'relation' => 'AND', array( 'key' => 'program_code', 'value' => $parentCode, 'compare' => '=', ), array( 'key' => 'program_code', 'value' => '', 'compare' => '!=', ) ) ); $partOfProgram = new WP_Query($args); $partOfProgram=$partOfProgram->posts; $partOfProgram=reset($partOfProgram); } if(count($partOfProgram)>0 && !empty($partOfProgram)){ return 'Part of the Long Program: '.$partOfProgram->post_title; } return 'Program Category: '.get_the_title($post->post_parent); } add_shortcode("application_deadline", "applicationDeadlineShortcode"); add_shortcode("registration_link", "registrationLinkShortcode"); add_shortcode("program_email", "programEmailShortcode"); post_parent); ?>
>
post_parent){?> post_parent);?>
/
```

There are also error boxes appearing after turning on WP_DEBUG:

```
( ! ) Notice: Undefined variable: categorie in C:\wamp\www\ipam.com\wp-content\themes\ipam\404.php on line 17
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0000  133440  {main}( )   ..\index.php:0
2   0.0010  135352  require( 'C:\wamp\www\ipam.com\wp-blog-header.php' )    ..\index.php:17
3   0.8550  15473264    require_once( 'C:\wamp\www\ipam.com\wp-includes\template-loader.php' )  ..\wp-blog-header.php:16
4   0.8730  15592192    include( 'C:\wamp\www\ipam.com\wp-content\themes\ipam\404.php' )    ..\template-loader.php:74

( ! ) Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\wamp\www\ipam.com\wp-content\themes\ipam\404.php on line 17
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0000  133440  {main}( )   ..\index.php:0
2   0.0010  135352  require( 'C:\wamp\www\ipam.com\wp-blog-header.php' )    ..\index.php:17
3   0.8550  15473264    require_once( 'C:\wamp\www\ipam.com\wp-includes\template-loader.php' )  ..\wp-blog-header.php:16
4   0.8730  15592192    include( 'C:\wamp\www\ipam.com\wp-content\themes\ipam\404.php' )    ..\template-loader.php:74
( ! ) Notice: Undefined variable: categorie in C:\wamp\www\ipam.com\wp-content\themes\ipam\404.php on line 20 Call Stack #TimeMemoryFunctionLocation 10.0000133440{main}( )..\index.php:0 20.0010135352require( 'C:\wamp\www\ipam.com\wp-blog-header.php' )..\index.php:17 30.855015473264require_once( 'C:\wamp\www\ipam.com\wp-includes\template-loader.php' )..\wp-blog-header.php:16 40.873015592192include( 'C:\wamp\www\ipam.com\wp-content\themes\ipam\404.php' )..\template-loader.php:74
( ! ) Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\wamp\www\ipam.com\wp-content\themes\ipam\404.php on line 20
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0000  133440  {main}( )   ..\index.php:0
2   0.0010  135352  require( 'C:\wamp\www\ipam.com\wp-blog-header.php' )    ..\index.php:17
3   0.8550  15473264    require_once( 'C:\wamp\www\ipam.com\wp-includes\template-loader.php' )  ..\wp-blog-header.php:16
4   0.8730  15592192    include( 'C:\wamp\www\ipam.com\wp-content\themes\ipam\404.php' )    ..\template-loader.php:74
">
( ! ) Notice: Undefined variable: categorie in C:\wamp\www\ipam.com\wp-content\themes\ipam\404.php on line 20
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0000  133440  {main}( )   ..\index.php:0
2   0.0010  135352  require( 'C:\wamp\www\ipam.com\wp-blog-header.php' )    ..\index.php:17
3   0.8550  15473264    require_once( 'C:\wamp\www\ipam.com\wp-includes\template-loader.php' )  ..\wp-blog-header.php:16
4   0.8730  15592192    include( 'C:\wamp\www\ipam.com\wp-content\themes\ipam\404.php' )    ..\template-loader.php:74

( ! ) Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\wamp\www\ipam.com\wp-content\themes\ipam\404.php on line 20
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0000  133440  {main}( )   ..\index.php:0
2   0.0010  135352  require( 'C:\wamp\www\ipam.com\wp-blog-header.php' )    ..\index.php:17
3   0.8550  15473264    require_once( 'C:\wamp\www\ipam.com\wp-includes\template-loader.php' )  ..\wp-blog-header.php:16
4   0.8730  15592192    include( 'C:\wamp\www\ipam.com\wp-content\themes\ipam\404.php' )    ..\template-loader.php:74
/
```

Comment: What is a **wordpress server**?

Comment: 1. How did you change the root name of your website (where) and how do you set it. 
2. can you check your source code from the website - do you receive something like "<a href=""abc class=""yourclass>" (you see the double quotes?)

Comment: Anyways, the first error just says, that you are using jQuery without having it loaded yet.

Comment: I am using a wampserver so the setup called for me to simply put the wP files into a folder that I create and then use the url http://localhost/ipam.com

Comment: You have to create a virtualhost in order for some PHP functions to work

Comment: oh ok, so the WAMP server doesnt do that automatically?

Comment: Ok I found an artical how to setup virtual hosts on wAMP. I am going to try it and get back to you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to create a virtualhost in order for some PHP functions to work properly. Wordpress uses them:

This is an example vhost, you have to create it in

`C:\wamp\bin\apache\Apache2.4.4\conf\extra`

```
<Virtualhost *:80>
    ServerAdmin programierung@drive.eu
    DocumentRoot "C:\wamp\www\yourProject\web"
    ServerName yourProject.localhost.de
    ErrorLog "logs/yourProject-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/yourProject-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

Aswell you have to uncomment the line **500**
`Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf`

Like this your vhost file will get loaded.

The last change you have to make is to create an entry in your hosts file located in

`127.0.0.1   yourProject.localhost.de`

Explanation: 127.0.0.1 is your local pc. yourProject.localhost.de is the domain you can use, to access the website.

Now you have to restart your wamp server and access your project by typing in "yourProject.localhost.de". Remember to change the ROOT_URL in your wordpress configuration.

Other typical problems by setting a wordpress instance on another server:

An issue with the quotes, wordpress uses different quotes. Like this, you sometimes receive double quotes.

Easy fix is to add this code to your functions.php located in your Theme, like this you remove all weird wordpress filters

```
remove_filter('the_content', 'wptexturize');
remove_filter('the_title', 'wptexturize');
remove_filter('the_excerpt', 'wptexturize');
remove_filter('comment_text', 'wptexturize');
remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' );
```

Comment: Ok the virtual host got rid of all those errors, the remove_filter code was already in place by the people that designed the WP site. All I am getting now is "You don't have permission to access /ipam.com/ on this server."

Comment: I made the changes but now my Apache server will not start

Comment: @mattgcon Probably, you have set a wrong path, check your error log if you click on the icon in the bottom bar. Make sure all your vhost path' are correct.